# Can't search pre-migration emails with outlook 2010 after migrating to exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007, outlook-2010, outlook-web-app

We've recently migrated from a Exchange 2007 server to two Exchange 2010 servers. After the migration was set in production, we set a new citrix XenApp-environment with Outlook 2010 in production instead of Outlook 2007 that we used on our old terminal server.

**The problem**: Search results in Outlook 2010 (non-cached) and OWA only includes emails received  and sent after the migration. Outlook 2007 on the old terminal server includes results from the beginning of time but results prior to the migration take time to show up (seems like "indexing on the go").

Tested solution: 
 - Cached mode: works but we can't have everybody cache their emails on our terminal solution.
 - Rebuild search index: Tried the script `ResetSearchIndex.ps1` but it didn't help.

Not tested yet:
 - Rebuild search index: The manual version of a search index rebuild hasn't been tried yet but is it different form the ps1-script?

Comment: Which service pack are you running? A similar issue and rollup update - http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2756485 . The latest update is SP2 with rollup 5-v2.

Comment: Figured out that the search indexes weren't replicated between the two mailservers, so while the search index on server 0 were correct, the search index on server 1, used by the users of Outlook 2010, weren't correct.

Comment: If you managed to fix the problem yourself post it as an answer.

Comment: Bacouse my serverfault-account is so new, I'll have to wait to post my answer. The answer is: 
"The search indexes weren't replicated between the two mailservers, so while the search index on server 0 were correct, the search index on server 1, used by the users of Outlook 2010, weren't correct.

Did a reset of the search index on the other server as well, and now everything works perfectly."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search indexes weren't replicated between the two mailservers, so while the search index on server 0 were correct, the search index on server 1, used by the users of Outlook 2010, weren't correct.

Did a reset of the search index on the other server as well, and now everything works perfectly.